# Uniform Continuity of a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ be a complex function
$$f(z)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$
with $D=\{z:0<|z|\le R\}$ for some $R$. The results from numerical experiment suggest that this function is not uniformly continuous on $D$ for any $R>0$ since for any $R>0$, $f(D)$ is an unbounded set. How to (dis)prove this analytically? Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about continuous extensibility of uniformly continuous functions to the closure of their domain?

Comment: I believe $f$ can't be continuously extended to $\{z:|z|\le R\}$

Answer (score 0):

First, observe that if $b_n=i/n$, then $f(b_n)\to\infty$. Suppose that $f$ was uniformly continuous on $D$. Choose $\varepsilon=1$. Then there exists $\delta$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Let $x=\delta/2$. There exists a neighborhood of the origin contained within $B(x,\delta)$. Therefore, all but finitely many points of the sequence $(b_n)$. Since $f(b_n)\to\infty$, we may choose $N$ such that $|f(b_N)|>|f(x)|+1$ and such that $b_N\in B(x,\delta)$. Choosing $y=b_N$, we have a contradiction. Therefore $f$ is not uniformly continuous.